# When I’m around, I make you smile - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> When I’m around, I make you smile
>
> My powers reach a few good miles
>
> It’s weird enough, you mentioned food
>
> But more bizarre, just here you stood
>
> Joy or dismay, I’m on my way
>
> The truth always, I will convey

**Who Am I?**

edit:

Hint 1:

> I am an object. A specific profession cannot work without me.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Please note that as a community, we prefer people don't specify "my first puzzle" in the title or question, so I've edited out that part from the title. You may definitely do so in a comment below the question.

Comment: Also, congratulations on your first riddle, it looks to be a good one. Take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) as well to familiarize yourself with the site.

Comment: Thanks Phylyp! I see a lot of creative answers and I think this is the magic of riddles! If in case my riddle is not clear enough for guessing, do I need to provide the answer at some point?

Comment: After a day or more,  you can provide a hint,  to help steer people towards the answer.You'd want to provide the answer only after several days have gone by, and various hints haven't helped.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDITED with new answer for part 3

I'd say it's

> a camera

When I’m around, I make you smile

> we smile when our photos are taken

My powers reach a few good miles

> we can take photos of things that are far away

It’s weird enough, you mentioned food

> "Cheese"  <s>we all know someone who posts photos of his lunch</s>

But more bizarre, just here you stood

> we stand still to take a photo

Joy or dismay, I’m on my way

> photos are always taken during important events even if they are tragic

The truth always, I will convey

> a photo is just a representation of reality (unless photoshop was used)

hint 1 :

> I am an object. A specific profession cannot work without me. Being a photographer without camera would be quite hard

Comment: Yay you got it! I hope everyone enjoyed it. You got all the points except for the food one, think of what we usually say when we use it :D

Comment: Nice answer, and @RockCheung nice puzzle, and a neat hint.

Answer (score 3):

Is it a

> Rainbow !?

- It definitely brings a smile,
- It reaches a few good miles,
- Weird, but rainbow lolly
- Bizarre, it stands there
- Joy or dismay, it will come and make you smile anyway
- truth of light it conveys

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Endorphins?

It is present during a smile. The total length of nerves is a lot of miles. It is also present in foods, joy or dismay.

Comment: This is a nice answer! But it is not the one I have in mind

Comment: I see. Think I must.

Answer (score 1):

Could the answer be:

> Santa Claus?

When I’m around, I make you smile

> Santa claus makes everyone smile when hes in the neighbourhood

My powers reach a few good miles

> Santa can travel all over the world

It’s weird enough, you mentioned food

> Santa is associated with food i.e. Milk, cookies, carrots for his reindeer etc

But more bizarre, just here you stood

> Its a lot more bizarre that someone believed not to be real is actually stood in your general location

Joy or dismay, I’m on my way

> Regardless of whether or not you are happy or sad at christmas, santa will always arrive

The truth always, I will convey

> Tricky one, but the truth (for a child especially) is that Santa is real.

Answer (score 0):

I have two guess:

> Ice cream Truck
>  Your Pet (Dog)

When I’m around, I make you smile

> Well, you smile when you see the ice cream truck coming
>  You also smile when you are around your pet

My powers reach a few good miles

> You can her the ice cream truck jingle from miles
>  Your pet can run and smell you for a few miles

It’s weird enough, you mentioned food

> Ice cream
>  Dog food?

But more bizarre, just here you stood

> Don't know this one

Joy or dismay, I’m on my way

> The ice cream truck comes even if you are happy or sad
>  If you are happy or sad, your pet is there to comfort you

The truth always, I will convey

> Don't know this one either

Answer (score 0):

> chocolate

when I am around I make you smile

> alot of people like chocolate

it’s weird enough, you mentioned food

> as far as I know chocolate is a food right ;p